# Adding the controls to a array of buttons c#

Tags: c#, arrays, button, controls

I am in the middle of a project and need to add  functions into a array of buttons so each button will run that function upon click. I have created the array which also uses a struct for all properties during initialising. I cannot hard code the functions because a previous function sets the size and order of the button array.
I have looked through the net and can't seem to find a specific answer that is relevant. I am fairly new to programming (in my 2nd year) so sorry if my terminology is fresh from college.
Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Write your common event handler as follow with proper parameters.

```
private void MyCommonFunctionForAllButtons(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Write the logic you want to execute once any button is pressed.
}
```

Assign the same event handler for all the buttons in your array.

```
foreach( Button button in buttonArray ) 
{
    button.Click += MyCommonFunctionForAllButtons;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through a list of buttons and assign an onclick handler?

```
foreach( Button button in buttons ) {
    button.Click += methodName;
}
```

Or was there something more to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I guess:

```
Button[] buttons = ... ;
for (int i=0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
{
    Button b = buttons[i];
    b.TabIndex = i;
      ... set other properties here, as desired....
    b.Click += new System.EventHandler(clickHandler[i]);
}
```

If this isn't what you were thinking, maybe you could show some code to illustrate what you want.